# How to add CLIPC library in netbeans 7.0

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, interprocess

CLIPC is a library for interprocess communication in Java.
I have downloaded it from https://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=255796

There were 3 files inside the downloaded zip file.

1. clipc.dll,
2. clipc.jar and
3. libclipc.so

Now if i try to add the extracted folder or the zip file to my project in the Netbeans libraries section, then Netbeans doesn't recognize the packages inside the CLIPC library.

On the other hand if I just add the CLIPC.jar file then Netbeans recognizes the code which I type.
But when I try to compile it I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no clipc in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
at com.lts.ipc.IPCPackage.basicInitializePackage(Unknown Source)
at com.lts.ipc.IPCPackage.initializePackage(Unknown Source)
at com.lts.ipc.semaphore.SemaphoreNative.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.lts.ipc.semaphore.Semaphore.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.lts.ipc.semaphore.Semaphore.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ipc.IPC.main(IPC.java:15)

Java Result: 1
```

This might be beacuse clipc.jar file must not have been mapped with the clipc.dll file.

So can anyone suggest me where should I place those clipc.dll and libclipc.so files ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question

-Djava.library.path="c:\path\to\the\dir\that\contains\the\dll"

Place the above line in "Project -> Properties -> Run -> VM options" field.